# How to tell LyX to put every sentence on its own line?

Tags: lyx, git

I'm planning to write my master thesis using LyX. In order to keep track of recent changes, I want to export the LyX source files to normal LaTeX source files and put these in a Git repository. In the LaTeX source files, I want each sentence to be on its own line so that I can track changes of my text in a more fine-grained way.

Is there maybe a macro or a command with which I can tell LyX to put each sentence on its own line in the exported LaTeX source files? If not, is there a way to write my own macro which can achieve that? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: My first thought is to write a script that will search the .tex file for periods and insert a `\\\` after each one to create a new line. The result probably won't be perfect but it should be a decent enough starting point.

Are you comfortable in any scripting languages?

Comment: Have you seen [`latexdiff`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/)?

Comment: @Dennis Inserting a `\\ ` doesn't help here because I don't want each sentence to be on a separate line in the generated PDF file but only in the LaTeX source file.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I know `latexdiff` but it's not as nice as a real version control system. Besides that, it's not an answer to my question.

Comment: @PeterStahl Without some form of coding convention, version control is impossible. Personally I always format the LaTeX input by hand. Putting every sentence on one line may be regarded as a coding convention, but it'll be one that's going to make it very difficult to find bugs.

Comment: I don't understand what you're after then. I took it that you wanted each sentence on its own line in the LaTeX source document (once exported) but not in LyX. Aren't you creating the PDF directly from LyX, not from the LaTeX source file you export?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Putting each sentence on its own line helps to avoid merge conflicts. Also, it facilitates the overview of the changes in the different commits.

Comment: @Dennis It doesn't matter whether I create the PDF from LyX or from the LaTeX source file. Putting each sentence on its own line is for revision control only, not for the desired PDF output (i.e. in the PDF I want to have normal paragraphs etc.).

Comment: @PeterStahl My comment already suggests that putting evey sentence on a single line helps version control. My main concern is that this is not very useful when it comes to debugging/editing the LaTeX input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use Version Control in LyX. (At least in the Mac version there is a menuitem under File menu.) I have just tried it today and it works nicely, I can smoothly compare my newer submissions with older ones, with the modified interface in Version Control.

Im not sure what is the case in other systems, but on mac using the built-in Version Control is far better than using git.

UPDATE:

But be prepared for frequent of check-ins and outs as I have checked-in stuff after two days and it started counting the differences... I waited up to 5000, that was in 5mins and closed the comparison... :(

Comment: Ah, thanks for the note. I'm using the Mac version and wasn't aware that `rcs` is used for version control. I thought that `svn` would have been used instead. Since there doesn't seem to be a solution for my problem, I will probably stick to the LyX-internal version control and put the respective master file (extension `*.lyx,v`) in my Git repository. That should work as well.

Comment: Yeah, I have just had some surprise :S Anyway, you can still use svn or git, with the .lyx files, since the actual text in .lyx files is quite well readable if you do not turn on compression. So you have a good chance at being able to see the differences.